# Cloning famous sites using Drupal. What are the limits?

Tags: drupal

We hear a lot about some "Drupal shops" demonstrating Drupals strengths by cloning some very famous websites using Drupal and only Drupal. I want to know, can Drupal really leverage the same strengths the original web app does? What are the limits of Drupal anyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really are no limits as to what you can do with Drupal. The only limits are the limits you set yourself.

**Looks:**

To make a website *look* like a famous website with Drupal, you need a good designer. Now when the design is done someone will need to integrate that into the template code. Thats either the designer or programmer. Depending on the complexity of the template system.

**Functionality:**

To make a website *work* like a famous website with Drupal, you need a good programmer that knows his way around with the system. You can write plugins for Drupal that can do pretty much anything. If plugins don't do it for you, just extend Drupal.

There are no limits as to what you can do with Drupal.

Just remember, if the time it takes you to modify it to fit your needs exceeds the time it would take to make your own, then just do it yourself. :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

No limit, which is kinda the point.

If you want to build a web application, you can start with Drupal.

A funny video explains:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZ-s3DRZJKY

Drupal is both a framework and an application. The application can be extended through the framework.

The application, out of the box, handles:

- user management and authentication
- file uploads
- search engine
- content creation
- and much, much more

The application is also easily extensible via the vast array of modules available.

The framework is a hook based API that lets you can extend the application as much as you want.

The framework includes

- a content API
- a forms API
- a user API
- a fields API
- and many more APIs
- a database abstraction layer
- jQuery

You can use the framework to write modules, which add functionality to the application. So, with a Drupal programmer, you can make the application do whatever you want.

The theming rocks. As vanneto noted, the site can be made to look however you want. The presentation is in the theme layer and doesn't affect the functionality at all; users can have separate themes, pages can have separate themes, the theming system supports sub-themes themes can be changed without having to worry about nearly anything.

Some examples:
- theonion.com
- whitehouse.gov
- nasa.gov
- grammy.com

And here is a list of some high profile sites in various industries:

http://drupal.org/cases

Essentially, if people log in and create content (no matter if it the content is a news story, car reservation, music lesson confirmation, blog post, product, or whatever), then Drupal might be a great starting point for your application.

I am a Drupal module developer, and I love the framework. The applications I have recently built in Drupal include online databases for a set of yoga studios, a sports league, a magazine, and a web interface to a FileMaker database. Notice how random that list is? You can build whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a limit.  If there is a functionality which no module or combination and/or modification  (with overrides) of modules can satisfy, then you can use Drupal as a framework and develop a module that gives you that functionality.  So the real limit is PHP, and PHP is robust enough to handle any task.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is, at its core, just a system that generates HTML based on some rules. This is true for every web application - they can all, with varying amounts of difficulty, generate whatever HTML the developer wants.